# Need best way to to avoid Replication Re-Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I need the best way for the scenario because of which I got irritated.
I do have 3 Production database Servers Srv1, Srv2 and Srv3.
I configure transactional replication among these servers.
Srv1 is Publisher and Srv2 and Srv3 are subscribers.

On production server everything running fine without any problem.

I have QA environment same as production replication configured.
On request of QA team, I need to refresh QA with production databases weekly (almost), which cause to fail replication in QA environment.

Because I have 1000 tables dropping and re-creating publications takes too much time on Srv1.

If I refresh database without dropping publication and recreate publication using backup script I get `The process could not execute ‘sp_repldone/sp_replcounters’`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What @Kin said is correct but may be time-consuming (if you have really big tables involved in replication) when you need to run Snapshot.

Here are the steps that you can omit the snapshot

- Script out QA replication and change @sync_type parameter value (highlighed
  below)

  exec sp_addsubscription **@sync_type = 'Replication Support Only'**, ... (other paramaters should remain the same)
- Remove replication (you can write a script to do this, note, first
  remove subscriptions then publisher, but do NOT remove distributor)
- Restore PROD db on QA publisher
- Restore PROD db on QA subscribers.
- Run the replication setup script on QA publisher
- Test your replication by inserting/updating a few test records and see whether the replication works as expected.

This link talks about another ways that can avoid snapshot and may be of help (but I never tried myself)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2010/03/16/deep-dive-on-initialize-from-backup-for-transactional-replication/

1st step of scripting out QA replication is one time work and you can actually automate all these steps (after step 1 modification is done) via t-sql scripts, and using sqlcmd.exe or powershell to drive the t-sql scripts. I used this way frequently before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that what you have to deal with when you refresh your QA with PROD backups that is involved in T-Rep.

What I have done is

- Script out QA replication
- Remove replication
- Restore with overwrite QA from PROD
- Run the QA replication scripts
- start snapshot - as now your subscribers are outdated in QA.
- Let the log reader agent replicate the transactions.

You may want to look into

- Initialize replication using backup and
- Restore database .. with KEEP_REPLICATION option.

Comment: I used this method, but it creates all publications available at production database server. When I try to remove subscribers, it says the Subscriber is not configured for the publisher (QA Publisher) and doesn't delete that.